# Set dropdown value in JSP

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

I have a variable in my jsp **fileType**, and i want to set the fileType as the selected value of a dropdown list.

```
<td>
<select name="file_type" id="file_type" class="mlselect">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="true" <%= ("".equals(fileType))?("selected='selected'"):""%> >-----Select A File Type -----</option>
    <option id="IMAGE" value="IMAGE" <%= ("IMAGE".equals(fileType))?("selected='selected'"):""%>>Image file</option>
    <option id="VIDEO" value="VIDEO" <%= ("VIDEO".equals(fileType))?("selected='selected'"):""%>>Video file</option>
</select>
```

Above will be my code, however it is not working. Any help please?

Comment: try selected="true"...and wats this extra stuff `<%= ("".equals(fileType))?("selected='selected'"):""%>` ????//

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone thanks for your reply, sorry to inform u it doesn't work as well. <%%> represents scriplet tags, and u are able to include java coding in your jsp within the tag however it is not advisable (but i have to implement it this way). And within my scriplet tag, it does an if-else check. Correct me if i am wrong, thanks! Cheers

Comment: i know those r scriptlets but y in the middle of option?